# How to determine which div is currently displayed behind a button when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, togglebutton, jquery

I'm using Javascript/Jquery to have a button toggle which div is displayed in the user's window. I have my initial background div `#container` which gets toggled with a different div if the user clicks on a certain location. A back button is toggled **on** once the new div is displayed. I want the back button to switch the div back to the initial `#container` if it is pressed. The back button's display should be toggled **off** again if this happens.

Since I have different divs that the back button shows up in, I need to determine which background div the user is viewing in order to toggle that specific div **off** and the #container back **on**. The container will not display again if I do not toggle the current div **off**.

Here's my code for an example of one instance:

JS:
`$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#backButton").click(function(e)
    {
        if(THE CURRENT DIV IS REGION 1)
        {
            $("#container").toggle(); //toggle the container on
            $("#region1").toggle(); //toggle region 1 off
            $("#backButton").toggle(); //toggle the back button off
        }
    });
});`

Obviously, I do not know what code to use to determine which div the user is looking at. I tried `if(document.getElementById('region1');)` but it didn't work; I didn't think it would, but that's the direction I'm going as to how to determine the current div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($('#region1').is(":visible")){ etc... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a back button located in the DOM inside the div `region1`, you could use:

```
    if($(this).parents("#region1").length > 0)
```

Which says "if the number of parents of this button containing ID region 1 are non-zero".  For more information see [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).  In general the [traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) functions in jQuery will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for:
http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is switching two DIVs back and forth, you don't even have to check which DIV is currently displayed, because the `.toggle()` function should do that for you out-of-the-box.

Consider you have two DIVs, make sure one is hidden and one is shown, like so:

```
<div id="region1">foo</div>
<div id="region2" style="display:none;">bar</div>
```

Now, when you click on the button, you just have to call `.toggle()` on both of them.

```
$('#backButton').click(function(){
    $('#region1, #region2').toggle();
});
```

You can even get by with using only one button to do that, and just switch the text inside the button if you'd like.

```
// inside the click handler
$(this).val( $(this).val() == 'Next' ? 'Back' : 'Next' );
```

Full code example here: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Phye8/)

Comment: `Since I have different divs that the back button shows up in, I need to determine which background div the user is viewing` - therefore, toggle will not work as it is not switching between two states but many.

Comment: +1 ah, great job pointing that out. completely missed that, thanks. :)

Comment: Yes, thank you for giving advice, but Bllly Moon completely solved my problem. ;)